# VueJs/Nuxt Filter an array, error _vm.filtered.. is not a function

Tags: vue.js, filter, vuejs2

I am new to Vue/Nuxt and try to filter an array.

```
computed: mapState({
  entries: state => state.archives.archives
}),

filteredArchive, function (objects, key) {

  if (objects) {
    return objects.filter(function(object) {
      return object.tag === key
    })
  }
```

I want to get the result in a loop:

```
<li v-for="(entry, index) in (entries | filteredArchive('test'))">{{ entry.title }}</li>
```

This fails..
What is wrong in my approach..

Thanks for help.

Comment: P.S., avoid using phrases like "what is the best way" or people will close your question as being opinion based. Say "How can I fix this error" instead. Allow the voting system make the best answer rise to the top.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a computed property for "filteredArchive" instead of a filter. In fact, I believe filters are going away in Vue 3. You can put it in a mixin if you need to share the logic across components.

Comment: Thanks for advice, yes looks better. But still my question.. how to get the result into the loop..?

Comment: If it's a computed property then you don't need to do anything special. ` v-for="(entry, index) in myComputedProperty"` @Werner

Comment: Pls. read my question again.. somewhere I have to give params to the function..

Answer (score 0):

ok. this is my solution for now:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(entry, index) in filteredByTag(entries, 'test')">
      <nuxt-link :to="'archive/' + entry.id">{{ entry.title }}</nuxt-link>
    </li>
  </ul>

computed: mapState({
  entries: state => state.archives.archives,
}),

methods: {
  filteredByTag(entries, tag){
    return entries.filter((entry) => {
      return entry.tag.match(tag)
    })
  }
},
```